# Display Epub Files using Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder, epub

I am making a epub reader flex project on web, air and mobile. I'm quite good in understanding the facts from the below link. Its just shows how to unzip the epub file, either local or in web.
http://designwithoutdesign.blogspot.com/2010/07/working-with-epub-files-in-flash-and.html

anyone, help me how can I display it in both web and air. I Just succeeded in displaying the PDF in web and mobile, but not the epub. Need a swc for displaying epub. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

epub is a zip containing xml and html files. so I don't see a reason why you need flex for that, you can render the html directly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?